# Very uninformative error with SQLite query

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using `Apache Cordova` which is a Hybrid mobile application platform. I'm using the following plugin `cordova-sqlite-storage` for handling my SQLite. The syntax is completely identical to that of WebSQL.

Considering this is used with `AngularJS` I have my database set up in a factory, here is how I've always called a query to be ran against my database without any problems:

```
    query: function(query, params, callback) {
        try {
            factory.database.transaction(function(tx) {
                if(callback) tx.executeSql(query, params, callback, function(transaction, error) { console.log("ERROR"); });
                else tx.executeSql(query,params);
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    }
```

However today, everything changed. Please note the "ERROR" callback is usually not present, however in this case it does not fire anyway.

So my issues are as follows:

1. The Query does not execute, or so I believe, because the application hangs at this point.
2. The Query does not fire the failed or success callbacks.
3. The catch block is fired with a very uninformative error. (Atleast to myself).

The error displayed is as follows:

```
ERROR: , {"line":29,"column":21,"sourceURL":"http://10.0.0.20:8100/js/factories/database.js"}
```

For anyone curious about the scheme here are the following..

**Table**

```
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (message_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, content VARCHAR NOT NULL, message_to INTEGER NOT NULL, message_from INTEGER NOT NULL, message_sent INTEGER, message_inserted INTEGER, message_type INTEGER DEFAULT (0));");
```

**Insert Query**

```
"INSERT INTO messages (message_id, content, message_to, message_from, message_sent, message_inserted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
```

**Insert parameters**

```
[message.id, message.content, message.to, message.from, message.time, Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)]
```

I've verified that all of the parameters are correct, and use the correct format for the table. None of them are undefined or null.

**The fact that this issue is throwing in the try/catch block is bothering me, and the error is very, very confusing.**

Comment: Not to be glib, but are you sure everything is turned on? Is there anything running on port 8100? From your description it sounds like yesterday all of this worked and spontaneously it doesn't. maybe something is blocking your port or your server isn't turned on.

Comment: :8100 is the port that the application is being hosted on, it's being hosted through node. I'm using a live-reload server to the device. Everything is turned on, all of the proper application permissions are enabled. It just spontaneously exploded without any detail as to why.